# react ant design table with json - updating data without key problem

Tags: reactjs, json, antd

I would like to display some json data (coming from my backend and handled in a hook) in a similar way to this : https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-tree-data

I have a column with a checkbox and a column with an input (both must be editable by the user) and the final json state must be updated with the new datas.

Here you can find the structure of my json : https://pastebin.com/wA0GCs1K

Here you have a screen of the final result :
[image]

The code I used to fetch the data :

```
const [dataServiceInterface, setDataServiceInterface] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    CreateApiService.fetchDataServiceInterface(questionFiles, responseFiles).then((result) => {
      if (result != null) {
        setDataServiceInterface(result);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Here you have the code I used to update the attributes (column constant for the second part) :

```
const onInputChange = (key, record, index) => (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(key);
      console.log(index);
      console.log(record);
      console.log(e.target.value);

      dataServiceInterface.itemsQ[index][key] = e.target.value;
      
    };
// some other code here
{
        title: "Json Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        render: (text, record, index) => (
          <Input
            //defaultValue={text}
            value={text}
            onChange={onInputChange("name", record, index)}
          />
        ),
      },
```

Problem is (I think) : As I dont have a key defined in my json datas (parents and children), when I try to update the children it dosent work. I can't change the structure of the json because it's a business constraint. I was thinking of copying my json data in another state, then add the keys ... and still didn't try this solution and don't know if it works. I will update this if it's the case.

Meanwhile, if someone had the same issue and has any idea/hint/suggestion, would appreciate very much. Thx.

Comment: May be you should add your component's code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the component is not rendering the data once you have it. This can be solved by using `useState` hook, you should lookup for the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

I would love to get a little bit more of the component that you are building. But the approach to this would be something like this:

```
const Component = () {
   const [data, useData] = useState([]);
   const onInputChange = (key, record, index) => (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const data = // You get fetch the data here
      useData(data);
      
   };

   return <>
   {
    data && data.itemsQ.map((item) => {
        // here you display the information contained in each item
    })
   }
   </>
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry didn't detailed this part ... But the datas come from the backend and are handled in a hook :) I will update my post with this information. Thank you !

Comment: Here I updated the first part :) I will try your approach too, thank you :)